# Publish Video on Linkedin is working, but post cannot be opened

Tags: linkedin-api

We can create a video UGC Post successfully via API and also retrieve the UGC Post ID. But when we want to open the Post on linkedin (direct link) it does not show.

We also cannot retrieve the data:

"Not enough permissions to access: GET /ugcPosts/urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A6755042527050641408"

I know about the restriction of uploading a video, but if we are able to create the post ... its a little bit strange. If we are limited i would expect an error during create video post.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with the Rich Media Upload endpoints: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares

Specifically, use the recipe: `urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-video`

This allows you to upload the video and then add it to a post. Note, after you upload the video, you need to wait about 10-20 seconds for LinkedIn to complete processing. If you try to use the asset reference immediately, you'll get asset not found.

Comment: We tried it, but after uploading Video we Receive CLIENT_ERROR:

Comment: {
     "recipes": [
         {
             "recipe": "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-video",
             "status": "CLIENT_ERROR"
         }
     ],
     "serviceRelationships": [
         {
             "relationshipType": "OWNER",
             "identifier": "urn:li:userGeneratedContent"
         }
     ],
     "mediaTypeFamily": "VIDEO",
     "created": 1610954076710,
     "id": "C4D05AQH3yXSlHBewwQ",
     "lastModified": 1610954097007,
     "status": "ALLOWED"

Comment: any idea? we also set the correct Content-Type inside header on request

Comment: Could you add the code for the call you're making.